# How to simulate a USB drive

Tags: usb, simulation, usb-drive, hardware-interface, usbserial

Is it possible to simulate a USB drive with software only? I mean, for example, to expose a local memory space to the OS so the device manager will recognize it as a USB device.
I'm not familiar with hardware implementation, but I'm sure that it is possible somehow to emulate the USB protocol.

I began with this book - [USB Design By Example](http://www.intel.com/intelpress/usb/).

Can anyone please give me additional references to begin with?

Thank in advance!

Comment: I want to start with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a set of kernel-mode drivers that will do the job (block device driver and some supplementary code). Alternatively you can check our [virtual storage products](http://www.eldos.com/suppl/vs_compare.php) that let you create a virtual disk and expose it to the system.